# WindowBuilder: absolutely no effect on the GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 and I would like to use WindowBuilder too. My problem is it generates useless code for me. When I'm running my application I can see nothing but a little piece of the titlebar of the window of my program. This window's size is 0×0 no matter what have I set through the code. When I'm resizing it there is just a blank frame and nothing else. It turned out when I was debugging my code that the constructor - made by WindowBuilder - has been called and running without errors. However this constructor does not make any effect on my program. I have no clue what to do.

thanks

Comment: Can you update your qustion with that "useless" generated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go "New" > "Other" > "WindowBuilder" > "Swing designer" > "JFrame" (than name your class) you should get this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Stack extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Stack frame = new Stack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Stack() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}

}
```

In oposite way: Go "Help" > "Install new software" > " already installed". Check that you have installed these things (Swing designer and below):

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help. Since I wrote the question, I was thinking on the problem and I figured out something has must been messed up while the program getting more and more complex. In addition my operating system's UI sometimes just crashes when I'm typing and it may have caused some data loss also. Anyway I appreciate your help. Code check is not necessary yet, I'm building it up again.

Answer (score 0):

The best process is to let WindowBuilder create the framework of the GUI. With WB installed, just use the new Class icon in the toolbar. This will create the best method naming for WB to continue. WB cannot parse just any code. It needs to have some structure. See the example below.

[image: Example]